# Hello everyone, I am trying to receive all the data coming from a server but the loop does not stop

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, recv, python-sockets

So here is the code hangs on the while loop.
**client.py:**

```
import socket

ip = "127.0.0.7"
port = 65000
        
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect((ip, port))
    while True:
        file = input("Filename:")
        s.sendall(file.encode())
        b = b""
            
        while True:
            data = s.recv(4096)                        
            if not data:
                break 
            
            b+=data       
    
        with open(file, "wb") as f:
            f.write(donne)
        break
```

**server.py:**

```
import socket
import os

ip = "127.0.0.7"
port = 65000

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((ip, port))
    s.listen(5)
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    
    while True:
        receive = conn.recv(1024).decode()
        
        if os.path.exists(receive):
            
            with open(receive, "rb") as f:
                data = f.read()
                
            conn.sendall(data)            
            break
        
        else:            
            print("File not found")
```

The problem is with the client code.
I would like to receive all the data and write them to a file but the **loop** in **client.py** does not stop.

Comment: I tried 50000 and it works but the problem remains the same.

Comment: Weird, I just had a chance to run your client and server logic on my machine and they're fine. What does the file you're testing against look like?

Comment: I will try to test the client code with simple message. Thank you for answering.